# How to replicate ec2 "launch more like this" from the command line?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

The aws ec2 interface has a button called "launch more like this" that launches a second instance like the one selected. There is no similar functionality in the aws command line interface as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a working (though hacky) way to build an instance as a copy of another instance:

```
function cloneinstance {
  awsinstanceid=$1
  region=$2
  export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$region
  ami=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $awsinstanceid | grep INSTANCES | awk '{print $7}')
  privatekey=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $awsinstanceid | grep INSTANCES | awk '{print $10}')
  securitygroup=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $awsinstanceid | grep SECURITYGROUPS | awk '{print $2}')
  instancetype=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $awsinstanceid | grep INSTANCES | awk '{print $9}')
  subnet=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $awsinstanceid | grep NETWORKINTERFACES | awk '{print $9}')

  awsinstancedata=$(aws ec2 run-instances --image-id $ami --key-name $privatekey --security-group-ids $securitygroup --instance-type $instancetype --subnet-id $subnet)
  awsinstanceid=$(echo $awsinstancedata | awk '{print $9}')

  # AWS CLI sucks and doesn't return error codes so have to look for a valid id
  if [[ "$awsinstanceid" == i-* ]]; then echo -e "\t\tSuccessfully created. Instance ID: $awsinstanceid"; else echo -e "\t\tSomething went wrong. Check your configuration."; exit 1; fi 
  echo -e "\t\tWaiting for it to come up..."
  aws ec2 wait instance-running --instance-ids $awsinstanceid
  echo -e "\t\tServer is up and ready"
}

cloneinstance i-12345678 us-west-1
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to add `--output text` in all relevant places - the default is JSON and a lot of people don't change that.

Answer (score 1):

**Launch more like this** is a wizard and there is no CLI equivalent for it. You need to get the first instance attributes and use them to lauch the seconds instance with the same attributes (except for the ones that are unique to an instance). The [link](http://heylinux.com/en/?p=365) adds --clone option to awscli. Check it out.

Comment: helloV, I tried the tool in the link you sent but while it copies some attributes from instance to instance, the "launch more like this" i still giving me different behavior. It might be worth it to modify and extend this though if it can be changed to more closely replicate the wizard.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the answer you're looking for, but you if you can describe your initial instance with [Cloud Formation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html), then you can create more like it with:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --region your-region --template-body file://path-to-your-instance-description.json stack-name-must-be-unique
```

Answer (score 0):

The first comment works well. But for addiction i am adding an alternative using powershell core.

```
function LaunchMoreLikeThis ([String]$SourceInstanceName, [String]$CloneInstanceName, [String]$AMI_ID, [String]$InstanceType, [Int64]$Count = 1) {
 $SourceInstance = aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=$SourceInstanceName"
 $SourceInstance = $SourceInstance -join '' | ConvertFrom-Json -Depth 99

 $SourceInstanceAttr = $SourceInstance.Reservations.Instances[0];
 $InstanceId = $SourceInstanceAttr.InstanceId
 $SGs = $SourceInstanceAttr.SecurityGroups.GroupId | ForEach-Object { "`"$_`"" } | Join-String -Separator ' '  ;
 $PrivateKey = $SourceInstanceAttr.KeyName
 $SubnetId = $SourceInstanceAttr.SubnetId
 $UserData = pwsh -nologo -command "aws ec2 describe-instance-attribute --instance-id $InstanceId --attribute userData"
 $UserData = $UserData -join '' | ConvertFrom-Json -Depth 99
 $UserDataDecoded = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($UserData.UserData.Value))
 $UserDataFile = New-item -ItemType File -Path $([IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) -Name "user_data" -Value $UserDataDecoded -Force #You can change this to use a different user_data
 $Tags = "ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=$CloneInstanceName}]"
 pwsh -nologo -command "aws ec2 run-instances --image-id $AMI_ID --instance-type $InstanceType --security-group-ids $SGs --count 1 --subnet-id $SubnetId --key-name $PrivateKey --user-data file://$($UserDataFile.FullName) --tag-specifications `'$Tags`'"

}

LaunchMoreLikeThis -SourceInstanceName "<source_instance_name>" -CloneInstanceName "<clone_instance_name>" -AMI_ID "<ami_id>" -InstanceType "t3.medium"
```

In my case i needed to provide a different AMI, but you can extract it from the instance. And in my example i am extracting the user_data too.